# C2059 in VS2012 : How to initialize struct instance?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, gcc, struct

I have a .c file which I'm trying to compile in VS2012, but I get this error:

```
error C2059: syntax error : '.' main.c
```

According to what I've read it's a specific problem with the VS2012 compiler which I won't run into with other compilers. Whether or not this is true, I'm hoping that someone here can tell me how to fix this compiler error. How do I modify the code so that the code compiles and the behavior is the same?

This is what I have in my header file:

```
struct mystruct 
{
    struct someOtherStruct obj2;
    void* ptr1;
    void* ptr2;
    void* ptr3;
};
```

And this is what I have in main.c

```
void* P1 = NULL;
void* P2 = NULL;
void* P3 = NULL;

/* VS2012 complains about this syntax */
static struct mystruct obj = 
{
.ptr1 = P1,
.ptr2 = P2,
.ptr3 = P3,
};


void main(void)
{
    /* Empty for now */
}
```

Comment: using member names when initializing a struct is a feature of a 'recent' version of C.  It seems the C compiler is a bit behind the times as it does not recognize the latest syntax, so use the older syntax, as shown by @Praetorian.  The older syntax is still supported by all the C compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS2013 (finally) [supports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409293.aspx) designated initializers, so you'll have to upgrade your compiler to get this feature. Otherwise rewrite your initializer so that it conforms to C89.

```
static struct mystruct obj = 
{
    { /* initialize someOtherStruct members here */ },
    P1,  /* drop the member names */
    P2,
    P3,
};
```

If you don't want to bother with writing the initializers for `someOtherStruct`, reorder the members of `mystruct` so that the compiler will automatically zero-initialize `obj2`:

```
struct mystruct 
{
    void* ptr1;
    void* ptr2;
    void* ptr3;
    struct someOtherStruct obj2;
};

static struct mystruct obj = 
{
    P1,
    P2,
    P3,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

[Designated initializers](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-declarations-initializations/184401377) are a C99 (or newer) feature, and Visual Studio doesn't support C99 (or newer).  The equivalent VS-compatible initialization would look like:

```
static struct mystruct obj = 
{
    { 0 },
    P1,
    P2,
    P3
};
```

Both Clang/LLVM and GCC support C11 and are available for Windows, if you'd prefer to keep the same code.

Comment: I basically wrote the same answer as you, and then found [this](http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/07/vs2013_CPP_compliance). VS2013 does support designated initializers. And an [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409293.aspx) about the same.

Comment: Welcome to the future, I guess... ;-)